# Show that $θ=2sinθ$

Tags: trigonometry

This is probably an easy question for most people but for me I am stuck I don't get how this works. And I have no teacher as I am self studying . Any help is much appreciated.
[image]

It says this is the working out put I don't get it.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hint

The area of a triangle is given by, $$\frac{1}{2}ab\sin(\theta)$$
where a and b are the sides and $\theta$ is the included angle.

The area of a sector is given by, $$\frac{1}{2}\;\theta \ r^2$$
where r is the radius.

Comment: Thank you very much I added how its worked out but don't get the steps could you look at it please.

Comment: @Hiran The LHS is the area of the triangle and the RHS is the area of the sector minus the area of the triangle. Expand the RHS and it will be more clear.

Comment: AAAA i see thank you vert much!